# USB mouse has stopped working on Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: usb, 20.04, mouse

My Genius USB mouse has stopped working on my laptop, the pointer isn't even moving. I am sure it works fine since I've tried it on another laptop, and I've also tried plugging it to different USB ports to no avail. Touchpad is working fine.

As far as I can tell, the mouse is detected, since it shows up when I type `xinput` in terminal

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN0504:01 04F3:312A Mouse               id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN0504:01 04F3:312A Touchpad            id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=22   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Genius Wireless Device Consumer Control   id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Genius Wireless Device                    id=20   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer Wireless Radio Control               id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD User Facing: HD User Facing            id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=21   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Genius Wireless Device                    id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Genius Wireless Device System Control     id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Genius Wireless Device Consumer Control   id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I've looked for solutions all over the internet and tried all of them but none seems to help. Please tell me if more outputs are needed. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with a Microsoft Mobile Mouse 3500. When the dongle is plugged in, it's recognised if I run any one of `lsusb`, `hwinfo --mouse`, or `xinput` and is absent if I unplug it so I'm confident the dongle works. I also tried the `xinput reattach ...` in the answer from @user1091774 but it didn't work for me either.

Answer (score -1):

I've seen this happen from time to time with mice that have "loose" USB connections. You may be able to fix it with this:

```
xinput reattach 20 2
```

`20` being the ID of the mouse, and `2` being the core pointer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's still not working, even after I rebooted.